# How do I stop the browser storing form data which user entered in text fields

Tags: c#, asp.net

I dont know whether this simple task or not, but I tried to search in google but couldn't find anything.

I've a asp.net form and user enters some data in the text boxes provided. Whenever user submits the form, browser will save that form data. I don't want this form data to be saved in browser. How can I restrict the browser saving this form data without touching the browser settings?

Application is developed using asp.net and normal text boxes are used here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean you want the browser to stop remembering values entered, i.e. the browser's autocomplete?

```
<input type="text" name="text1" autocomplete="off">
```

Or this will work in FF and IE, but it's not XHTML standard:

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" autocomplete="off" />
```

Note that `autocomplete` is only defined in the HTML 5 standards, so it will break any validations you run against HTML 4.

If not, on PostBack, just clear the inputs:

```
TextBox.Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're meaning an `asp:TextBox` with "[...]*normal text boxes*[...]", then the control's `ControlState` is responsible for saving the entered value. Unfortunately, you can't disable the `ControlState` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx)).

Comment: Actually, the content of a ASP.NET TextBox is stored in the ViewState and this can be disabled.

Comment: @Remy yes, but if you disable the `ViewState` on the `asp:TextBox` and submit the `form`, your entered value will still be preserved in the `asp:TextBox`; the control's `ControlState` is responsible for this behaviour.